# difference between only and just

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

Can somebody explain me the difference between **only** and **just**? In which cases we can use them?

*ex:* I need *just* one glass of water, i need *only* one glass of water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice there would rarely be any significant difference in meaning between OP's two alternatives, but to the extent that they *could* carry different implications, it's that...

> 1: *I need **just** one glass of water*
>    All I need is a glass of water (not food, a bed for the night, or anything else significant)
>
> 2: *I need **only** one glass of water*
>    I don't need more than one glass of water (one glass is enough)

It's worth noting that #1 above *could* be used with the same sense as given for #2. The sense I've given for it would more often be expressed as...

> 3: *I **just need** a/one glass of water*

Comment: There are examples where they wouldn't be interchangeable though. i.e We can say "This is the **only** glass of water I have" but it would be incorrect to say "This is the **just** glass of water I have". If you wanted to use just in that case, you would have to say something like "I **just** have this one glass of water".